# Static Generic Class as Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary, clr

A static field in a generic class will have a separate value for each combination of generic parameters.  It can therefore be used as a Dictionary<Type, *whatever*>

Is this better or worse than a static Dictionary<Type, *whatever*>?

In other words, which of these implementations is more efficient?

```
public static class MethodGen<TParam> {
    public static readonly Action<TParam> Method = CreateMethod();
    static Action<TParam> CreateMethod() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Or,

```
public static class MethodGen {
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> methods 
              = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public static Action<T> GetMethod<T>() {
        //In production code, this would ReaderWriterLock

        Delegate method;
        if(!methods.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out method)
            methods.Add(typeof(t), method = CreateMethod<T>());
        return method;
    }

    static Action<T> CreateMethod<T>() { /*...*/ }
}
```

In particular, how does the CLR lookup the static fields by generic type parameter?

Comment: how do you implement your static Action<T> CreateMethod<T>() ?

Comment: And just when I was thinking about it! +1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like using generic types this way. In particular, I often have private nested generic classes for precisely this purpose.

The main thing I like about it is that it's hard *not* to get the initialization right this way (in terms of thread safety), given the way type initialization works. The only problem is what to do if initialization fails - occasionally I've resorted to remembering an exception to throw on first necessary access, but that's pretty rare.

I wouldn't like to guess at *exactly* how the CLR looks up the type via the type arguments, but I'm pretty sure it'll be optimised to heck and back :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the generic (first) version would do the dictionary lookup at compile time, and therefore perform better at runtime.

However, it might use more memory.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't profiled it (which is the only way to really answer this question - the difference in performance may be so small as to be meaningless) but I would hazard a guess that the locking is the expensive part. The CLR does do the locking for you - and does so in a way defined by experts in this field! - so I expect if there is a difference, it would be in favour of using the language feature rather than building it yourself with `Dictionary` + locking.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't store values for each generic type parameter as much as it really creates (conceptually anyways) N distinct classes - one for each type T that you use it with.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure that's right? I thought it only made one class for all reference types, and then one for each value type you might use it with.

Comment: It uses one copy of native code for all reference types, but there are distinct Type objects.