# Generic that takes only numeric types (int double etc)?

Tags: c#

In a program I'm working on, I need to write a function to take any numeric type (int, short, long etc) and shove it in to a byte array at a specific offset.

There exists a Bitconverter.GetBytes() method that takes the numeric type and returns it as a byte array, and this method only takes numeric types.

So far I have:

```
    private void AddToByteArray<T>(byte[] destination, int offset, T toAdd) where T : struct
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(toAdd), 0, destination, offset, sizeof(toAdd));
    }
```

So basically my goal is that, for example, a call to AddToByteArray(array, 3, (short)10) would take 10 and store it in the 4th slot of array. The explicit cast exists because I know exactly how many bytes I want it to take up. There are cases where I would want a number that is small enough to be a short to really take up 4 bytes. On the flip side, there are times when I want an int to be crunched down to just a single byte. I'm doing this to create a custom network packet, if that makes any ideas pop in to your heads.

If the where clause of a generic supported something like "where T : int || long || etc" I would be ok. (And no need to explain why they don't support that, the reason is fairly obvious)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I realize that I could just do a bunch of overloads, one for each type I want to support... but I'm asking this question because I want to avoid precisely that :)

Comment: I could have sworn I saw a question similar to this one before...

Comment: I did a quick search and nothing turned up :( Even if there is, perhaps some other newb will enter search terms similar to mine and find this thread in the future.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree that this can't be done; it's just that the design I'd propose to *do* it is a little weird (and involved).

Here's the idea.

### The Idea

Define an interface `IBytesProvider<T>`, with one method:

```
public interface IBytesProvider<T>
{
    byte[] GetBytes(T value);
}
```

Then implement this in a `BytesProvider<T>` class with a static `Default` property.

If this sounds familiar, it's because it's exactly how the `EqualityComparer<T>` and `Comparer<T>` classes work (heavily used in plenty of LINQ extension methods).

### The Implementation

Here's how I'd propose you set it up.

```
public class BytesProvider<T> : IBytesProvider<T>
{
    public static BytesProvider<T> Default
    {
        get { return DefaultBytesProviders.GetDefaultProvider<T>(); }
    }

    Func<T, byte[]> _conversion;

    internal BytesProvider(Func<T, byte[]> conversion)
    {
        _conversion = conversion;
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes(T value)
    {
        return _conversion(value);
    }
}

static class DefaultBytesProviders
{
    static Dictionary<Type, object> _providers;

    static DefaultBytesProviders()
    {
        // Here are a couple for illustration. Yes, I am suggesting that
        // in reality you would add a BytesProvider<T> for each T
        // supported by the BitConverter class.
        _providers = new Dictionary<Type, object>
        {
            { typeof(int), new BytesProvider<int>(BitConverter.GetBytes) },
            { typeof(long), new BytesProvider<long>(BitConverter.GetBytes) }
        };
    }

    public static BytesProvider<T> GetDefaultProvider<T>()
    {
        return (BytesProvider<T>)_providers[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

### The Payoff

Now, *finally*, once you'd done all this, what you'd do is simply call:

```
byte[] bytes = BytesProvider<T>.Default.GetBytes(toAdd);
```

No overloads needed.

Comment: You don't need a dictionary.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686630/static-generic-class-as-dictionary

Comment: @SLaks: but if you just defined the conversion function within a static generic type then I don't know how you could specify certain overloads of `BitConverter.GetBytes` for different types (how would the static generic type selectively choose between them?).

Comment: @SLaks: what I mean is, say I have the static type `DefaultBytesProviders<T>`. Then in the static constructor for that type, how do I instantiate the `IBytesProvider<T>` for `T`? `new BytesProvider<T>(BitConverter.GetBytes)`? That won't work as the correct overload can't be determined with just `T`. So it seems to me you *do* need to use a dictionary which you populate yourself. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can populate a static generic field instead of a dictionary:  `SDict<int>.Default = new BytesProvider<int>(BitConverter.GetBytes)`

Comment: @SLaks: OK, I see what you mean now. I thought you were suggesting that basically all of that code could be condensed into a simpler form. But really you're saying you could just cut out the dictionary but otherwise still declare a `BytesProvider<T>` instance for each of the legal types yourself. So I guess you would propose `SDict<T>` inherit from a non-generic base, and assign all the valid generic `Default` instances in that base's static constructor?

Comment: This is a really cool solution, and is exactly what I would implement if it was ever needed again. Unfortunately, simply typing up the couple of overloads I know I'd need was quicker. I was hoping there was a simple C# solution to this problem that I wasn't aware of. It would make a great addition to your library though!

Comment: @SLaks: Surprisingly, I tried the approach I just asked you about and [it didn't work as I expected it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652454/whats-the-best-way-to-ensure-a-base-classs-static-constructor-is-called). I'm curious: what approach do you generally use for this (not that it's the most common design in the world)? I'm considering just going with an internal class with something like an `Initialize()` method to initialize the "dictionary"; but I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: I've never needed a separate static initializer for these.  I always use the static ctor of the generic class.  In your case, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by first seperating the method into two parts, one to turn the value into an array of bytes, and another to insert them.  Then just use overloads:

```
        public static void AddToByteArray(byte[] destination, int offset, long value)
        { InsertBytes(destination, offset, BitConverter.GetBytes(value)); }

        public static void AddToByteArray(byte[] destination, int offset, int value)
        { InsertBytes(destination, offset, BitConverter.GetBytes(value)); }

        public static void AddToByteArray(byte[] destination, int offset, short value)
        { InsertBytes(destination, offset, BitConverter.GetBytes(value)); }

        private static void InsertBytes(byte[] destination, int offset, byte[] bytes)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, destination, offset, bytes.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing. I liked Dan Tao's solution, but for the simple problem I have it was a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work anyway, because which overload of `BitConverter.GetBytes()` to use is resolved at *compile time* and not at runtime, so the generic argument passed as `T` will not be used to help determine the `GetBytes()` overload.  Since there is no overload that accepts `object`, this approach could not work *even if* you could constrain `T` around some specific set of types.  So you are doubly-screwed here.

Your only real option here is to overload your `AddToByteArray` method for each numeric type you want to accept.  I know you don't want to do that, but there's little else you can do.  (You could accept an argument of `object` and use reflection to invoke the specific overload of `GetBytes()` based on the argument type, but that would be dog slow due to reflection and boxing overhead...)

Answer (score 1):

As a simplification of Dan Tao's solution in combination with SLaks' suggestion, here's a complete generic BitConverter:

```
public class BitConverter<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, byte[]> GetBytes = x => new byte[] { };

    static BitConverter()
    {
        BitConverter<byte>.GetBytes = x => new byte[] { x };
        BitConverter<bool>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<char>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<double>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<Int16>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<Int32>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<Int64>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<Single>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<UInt16>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<UInt32>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        BitConverter<UInt64>.GetBytes = x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
    }
}
```

Your example would then look like this:

```
private void AddToByteArray<T>(byte[] destination, int offset, T toAdd) where T : struct
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter<T>.GetBytes(toAdd), 0, destination, offset, sizeof(toAdd));
}
```

You would simply have to provide a GetBytes() method for each expected type to the static constructor. Which, by the way, is not limited to struct types, for example:

```
BitConverter<MemoryStream>.GetBytes = x => x.ToArray();
BitConverter<string>.GetBytes = x => Encoding.Default.GetBytes(x);
```

If there's no GetBytes() method for the generic type, it will return an empty array (but you might want to change the code to throw an Exception instead!).

Answer (score 0):

This is a real problem in C#, there is no common interface that all numeric types implement, you can restrict to `struct` and `new()`, but that still will allow structs with a parameterless constructor. If you really want to restrict it, you sadly have to use defined overloads for all numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about running on little-endian systems (like Windows), you could add a constraint on IConvertible (which I believe all the numeric types support), use that to convert the value to a 64-bit integer, get the bytes for that, and then throw away the bytes you know you don't need. Something like this:

```
private byte[] NumberToBytes<T>(T value)
    where T : new(), struct, IConvertible
{
    var longValue = value.ToUInt64();
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(longValue);
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, sizeof(T));
    return bytes;
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you're only working with integers -- it wouldn't work for float, double, or decimal. And as noted above, it would only work on little-endian systems; for big-endian, you would need to keep the last `sizeof(T)` elements from the array, not the first.