# references to Func's of different types

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, expression-trees

I have a singleton that can register a func to resolve an id value for each type:

```
public void RegisterType<T>(Func<T, uint> func)
```

for example:

```
RegisterType<Post>(p => p.PostId );
RegisterType<Comment>(p => p.CommentId );
```

and then i want to resolve the id for an object, like these:

```
GetObjectId(myPost);
```

where GetObjectId definition is

```
public uint GetObjectId(object obj)
```

The question is, how can i store a reference for each func to invoke it lately.
The problem is that each func has a different T type, and I can't do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>> _typeMap;
```

How can resolve it? Expression trees?

regards
Ezequiel

Comment: Can `Post` and `Comment` derive from a common interface with an `Id` property?

Comment: No, they cant derive from a common interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SLacks, following your advise i have changed my approach to:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>> _typeMap;

public void RegisterType<T>(uint typeId, Func<T, uint> func)
{            
    _typeMap[typeof(T)] = (o) => func((T)o);
}

public uint GetObjectId(object obj)
{
    return _typeMap[obj.GetType()](obj);
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Change `GetObjectId` to a generic function that takes a `T`.
   You can then [store the `Func<T, uint>`s in a generic static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686630/static-generic-class-as-dictionary) and call them by writing `FuncStorage<T>.Value(obj)`.
2. <strike>Use expression trees to</strike> Create `Func<object, uint>`s that calls the `Func<T, uint>` (using a cast) and put those in your `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>>`.
   **EDIT**: You don't need expression trees to do that; you can use a normal lambda expression which casts to `T`.  I was thinking of the reverse case (generating a generic delegate from a non-generic one), which does require expression trees.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, i cant change GetObjectId to GetObjectId<T> because i don´t known the type on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Expression Trees to do it the way you are suggesting, just need to nest the function when registering it.

```
public void RegisterType<T>(Func<T, uint> func){
             _typeMap.Add(typeof(T), obj=>func((T)obj));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Registration
    {
        public static Registration Instance = new Registration();

        private Registration()
        {
        }

        private Dictionary<Type, object> Dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public void Register<T>(Func<T, uint> aFunc)
        {
            Dictionary[typeof(T)] = aFunc;
        }

        public uint GetId<T>(T aT)
        {
            var f = Dictionary[typeof(T)];
            var g = (Delegate)f;
            return (uint) g.DynamicInvoke(aT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` is slow but in @Pedro's solution it's not necessary. The type actually can be known in this example such that `var g = (Func<T,unit>)f;` then `return g(aT)`. While this may not work for @eze1981 it could work for others.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that each func has a
>   diferent T type, and i cant do
>   something like these:
>
> ```
> private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>> _typeMap;
> ```

I'm not sure why you say this. This works:

```
class Post
{
    public uint PostId { get; set; }
}

static public void RegisterType<T>(Func<T, uint> getUintFromT)
{
    Func<object, T> toT = (t => (T)t);

    Func<object, uint> getUintFromObject = 
        @object => getUintFromT(toT(@object));

    _typeMap.Add(typeof(T), getUintFromObject);
}

static public uint GetObjectId(object obj)
{
    return _typeMap[obj.GetType()](obj);
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>> _typeMap 
        = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, uint>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterType<Post>(p => p.PostId);

        Post myPost = new Post();
        myPost.PostId = 4;

        var i = GetObjectId(myPost);

        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant change `GetObjectId` to `GetObjectId<T>` because i don´t known the type on runtime.

So, i have changed the dictionary definition to:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _typeMap
```

and then invoke it via Reflection:

```
public uint GetObjectId(object obj)
{
    uint id = 0;

    var objType = obj.GetType();

    // busco si el type está registrado
    if (_typeMap.Keys.Contains(objType))            
    {
        id = (uint) _typeMap[objType].Method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { obj } );                
    }

    return id;
}
```

Thank you all so much

Comment: Look at my answer. You can call GetId<T> without knowing the type at runtime. It will be inferred.

Comment: You should make the dictionary hold `Func<object, uint>`, by making a lambda that casts the object parameter to `T`.  This will be much faster.

Comment: @Pedro: Wrong.  Type inference can only happen at compile-time.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, the inference occurs at compile time. But look at my code. It will work.

Comment: @Pedro the inference at compile time will be `GetId<object>` thus when `Dictionary[typeof(object)]` won't be able to find anything. Actually since you used `DynamicInvoke` you didn't need to use generics at all on GetId thus `Dictionary[aT.GetType())]` would have made it work, though it would be slow, similarly slow to @eze1981 solution here since `DynamicInvoke` is just a short cut for `Method.Invoke`.