# Action<T> question

Tags: c#, .net, action

Given the code below:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>> controlDefaults = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>>()
    {
        { typeof(TextBox), c => ((TextBox)c).Clear() }
    };
```

How would I invoke the action in this case?  This is a code snippet taken from somewhere else, and the dictionary would contain many more instances of controls.  This willbe used for resetting all controls on a form to their default values.

So would I iterate as such:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    // Invoke action for each control
}
```

How would I then call the appropriate action from the dictionary for the current control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
controlDefaults[control.GetType()](control);
```

You could also [use a static generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686630/static-generic-class-as-dictionary) as the dictionary, and avoid casting:

```
static class ControlDefaults<T> where T : Control {
    public static Action<T> Action { get; internal set; }
}

static void Populate() {
    //This method should be called once, and should be in a different class
    ControlDefaults<TextBox>.Action = c => c.Clear();
}
```

However, you would not be able to call this in the loop, since you need to know the type at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the (control) part at the end of your first line that I was missing.

Comment: In other words, you were fetching the delegate from the dictionary, but you weren't doing anything with it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I couldn't figure out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You invoke it like a function.

E.g.:

```
Action<Foo> action = foo => foo.Bar();
action(f);
```

So in your case:

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
    controlDefaults[control.GetType()](control);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    Action<Control> defaultAction = controlDefaults[control.GetType()];
    defaultAction(control);

    // or just
    controlDefaults[control.GetType()](control);
}
```