# java how to create generic singleton class

Tags: java, generics, singleton

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SingletonAList<T> {

  private final ArrayList<T> aL = new ArrayList<T>();
  SingletonAList() {}
  public ArrayList<T> getList(T t) {
        return aL;
  }
}
```

What I am looking to do is have it return a Singleton List of the type if it exists; if not to create a new one of type T;

so example three getList calls are made;

```
getList(Obj1);
getList(Obj2);
getList(Obj1);

On first getList a new ArrayList<Obj1> would be created;
on second getList a new ArrayList<Obj2> would be created;
and on third getList the same arrayList from the first call would be returned.
```

Any implementation suggestions? I have been messing around...it seems that the new call must be in the getList call; and possibly another list of Types that have already been instantiated?

Comment: Due to type erasure, you can't do that.  (unless you use a `Map<Class<?>, ArrayList<?>>`)

Comment: “On first … would be created; on second … would be created;” Do you know what the “single” in “singleton” stands for?

Comment: I have done similar thing before, my implementation used a Map, just like @SLaks suggested.

Comment: @Holger: http://stackoverflow.com/q/686630/34397

Comment: @SLaks: so what? I don’t see the word “singleton” in this contribution.

Comment: @Holger: It's exactly what he's trying to do.  It's a very useful pattern, whether you call it a singleton or not.  (it is a singleton per-constructed-type)

Comment: @SLaks: if the questioner was aware of the fact that it’s not a singleton what he wants he was able to solve the problem on his own, maybe.

Answer (score -2):

One solution could be something like :

```
public class SingletonAList {

    private static Map<Class, List> lists = new HashMap<Class, List>();

    public static <T> List<T> getInstance(Class<T> klass) {
        if (!lists.containsKey(klass)) {
            lists.put(klass, new ArrayList<T>());
        }
        return lists.get(klass);
    }

}
```

After, you can call it with `SingletonAList.getInstance(String.class);`

Comment: That should be `Class<T>`

Comment: Yeah, forget them while typing :) Corrected

Comment: Now they are too many, you can't put `<T>` in the `lists` variable declaration.

Comment: Now you're using raw types - you should use wildcarded types instead, e.g. `Class<?>`.