# how to update all the fields with specific value in a list of object

Tags: c#, list, linq, reflection

I have a list of an object, I want to update all the fields that are "null" to string.empty.

here is the code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
    public string P3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a code which goes and finda all the null values in all the fields and change the value to string.empty

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list= new List<Class1>();
        var class1 = new Class1 {P1 = "P1-1", P2 = "P2-1", P3="null"};
        list.Add(class1);
        var class2 = new Class1 { P1 = "P1-2", P2 = "P2-2", P3 = "null" };
        list.Add(class2);

    }
```

so I would need the class1.P3 and class2.P3 to be found and their value to be replaced.

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind `null` is different than "null".

Comment: true, in my case, the data I was receiving as json was "null" instead of null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a short generic function like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ReplaceValues<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, object oldValue,
    object newValue)
{
    var properties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(t => Equals(t.GetValue(item), oldValue)))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(item, newValue);
        }
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This is more efficient than yours since your collection type is `TSource`, that means all of the types inside will have the same properties. Obtaining and caching those properties will speed up the process, because you're calling `Type.GetProperties()` only once and than you're operating and filtering those results.

**Update**

As discussed in the comment section below with [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765192/how-to-update-all-the-fields-with-specific-value-in-a-list-of-object/44765429?noredirect=1#comment76514044_44765429), it would be more suitable to have the method just modify the collection without returning any value:

```
private static void ReplaceValues<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, object oldValue,
    object newValue)
{
    var properties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(t => Equals(t.GetValue(item), oldValue)))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(item, newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare strings by value.  Use `Equals()`

Comment: @SLaks good idea, tho that involves boxing/unboxing, passing an `IEqualityComparer<T>` should be even better, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @SLaks what do you think about it now?

Comment: There is no point in using `EqualityComparer`, since there is no sane way to specialize (since you're handling arbitrary property types).  Just call `object.Equals(object, object)`.

Comment: Looks fine. For optimal perf, cache the properties across calls in a static class: https://stackoverflow.com/q/686630/34397

Comment: Thanks @Deadzone,

Comment: Hmm, why this is iterator method and not simple `void`? For unknown reason it yields each input item several times and also due to the deferred execution calling `myList. ReplaceValues("x", "y");` will do nothing.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you elaborate how can I reproduce the problem where the items will be returned multiple times? `myList. ReplaceValues("x", "y");` that's a bug, thanks for pointing it out, moving the `yield` statement in the `source` foreach loop would fix it. It's not a void because this will block the collection from later being accessed by LINQ or other `IEnumerable<T>` methods. Which is often the case with this type.

Comment: (1) I had in mind the bug that you just fixed :) (2) It's not natural though to have a mutating method which also `yield`s. The name implies *action* and it's easy to forget that  yielding methods do nothing until they get `foreach`-ed, `ToList()`-ed, `Count()`-ed etc. Basically it's a method which primary purpose is the side effect, which doesn't fit in the LINQ(uery) spirit.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your comments, but isn't my method exhibiting similar behavior to `.Select` isn't the latter using iterator internally as well?

Comment: It is, but `Select` converts (maps, projects) a source element to a destination element (by either selection a property or creating a *new* object). While your method is mutating source. Normally people do not expect a code like `foreach (var x in something)` to mutate the content of `x`. No LINQ method does that, although they can be abused to do that, which at the end will just cause issues to the one who is abusing them - I've seen that many times on SO when people try to use the "concise" LINQ `Select` + other operators to perform mutation and simply forget that it needs to be executed :)

Answer (score 0):

this will take care of it:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list= new List<Class1>();
        var class1 = new Class1 {P1 = "P1-1", P2 = "P2-1", P3="null"};
        list.Add(class1);
        var class2 = new Class1 { P1 = "P1-2", P2 = "P2-2", P3 = "null" };
        list.Add(class2);


        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var props2 = from p in item.GetType().GetProperties()
                        let attr = p.GetValue(item)
                        where attr != null && attr.ToString() == "null"
                        select p;

            foreach (var i in props2)
            {
                i.SetValue(item, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE::::

here is a more efficient way of doing it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            var list = new List<Class1>();
            var class1 = new Class1 {P1 = "P1-1", P2 = "P2-1", P3 = "null"};
            list.Add(class1);
            var class2 = new Class1 {P1 = "P1-2", P2 = "P2-2", P3 = "null"};
            list.Add(class2);



           var updatedList=  ReplaceValues(list, "null", string.Empty);

    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> ReplaceValues<TSource>
    (IEnumerable<TSource> source, object oldValue,
    object newValue)
    {
        var properties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
        var sourceToBeReplaced = source as TSource[] ?? source.ToArray();
        foreach (var item in sourceToBeReplaced)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(t => Equals(t.GetValue(item), oldValue)))
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(item, newValue);
            }
        }

        return sourceToBeReplaced;
    }
```

Comment: It will be much more efficient to get the properties only once.

Comment: how would you do it?

Comment: Just cache the result.

Comment: ...did you just answer your own question?

Comment: @Deadzone, can you explain how would you do it? what would you cache here?

Comment: @eric_eri64 I've added an answer.